# Pandas: How to update a dataframe and also append new entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using pandas=1.1.5. I want to update the values from df2 to df1. But df2 has new indices, and these are not appended to df1 when I use update. See below for details. Thank you

**df1**

```
      | Revenue |  Profit   | Sales |
0      |  100    |  300      |  1    |
1      |  500    |  900      |  3    |
2      |  200    |  100      |  4    |
```

**df2**

```
       | Sales |
0       | 10   |
6       |  12    |
```

**desired df**

```
      | Revenue |  Profit   | Sales |
0      |  100    |  300      |  10    |
1      |  500    |  900      |  3    |
2      |  200    |  100      |  4    |
6      |  Nan    |  Nan      |  12   |
```

**df from using update**

```
df1.update(df2)

      | Revenue |  Profit   | Sales |
0      |  100    |  300      |  10    |
1      |  500    |  900      |  3    |
2      |  200    |  100      |  4    |
```

Comment: This is a classic use case for [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) : `df2.combine_first(df1).loc[:,[*df1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Revenue':[100,500,200], 'Profit':[300,900,100], 'Sales':[1,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Sales':[10,12]}, index=[0,6])
df1 = df1.join(df2, how='outer', lsuffix='_df1')
df1['Sales'].fillna(df1['Sales_df1'], inplace=True)
df1.drop(columns=['Sales_df1'], inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

Using [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_df1', ''))
df1['Sales'].fillna(df1['Sales_df1'], inplace=True)
df1.drop(columns=['Sales_df1'], inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

OutPut:

```
   Revenue  Profit  Sales
0    100.0   300.0   10.0
1    500.0   900.0    3.0
2    200.0   100.0    4.0
6      NaN     NaN   12.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) method is somewhat restricted (not implemented) in terms of the approaches for joining (`join` parameter can only be `"left"`).

Therefore, you have to use both `update` and `concat`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Revenue': [100,5000,200], 'Profit': [300,900,100], 'Sales': [1,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Sales': [10,12]}, index=[0,6])

df1.update(df2, overwrite=True)
to_be_added = df2.loc[df2.index.difference(df1.index)]
dd = pd.concat([df1, to_be_added])
```

Results in:

```
   Revenue  Profit  Sales
0    100.0   300.0   10.0
1   5000.0   900.0    3.0
2    200.0   100.0    4.0
6      NaN     NaN   12.0
```

Comment: I noticed using update mess up some format. The original value  in df2= "01-10-2019  12:00:00 am " becomes "1569888000000000000" in  df1 after it is updated into df1. Anyway to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Apparently, you had a typed column. You can reinstate the type of the column by using `astype`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can `reindex` your dataframe before `update`:

```
out = df1.reindex(df1.index.union(df2.index))
out.update(df2)
print(out)

# Output:
   Revenue  Profit  Sales
0    100.0   300.0   10.0
1    500.0   900.0    3.0
2    200.0   100.0    4.0
6      NaN     NaN   12.0
```